# Bianchi chapter style not enough DPI

Tags: memoir, resolution

I am currently using the `bianchi` chapter style that has been provided by the `memoir` package. According to createspace, the DPI for the `bianchi` style is only ~100 DPI when it should be 300 DPI. How can I fix this?

Here is the MWE

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\chapterstyle{bianchi}
\chapter{My Chapter 1}
\end{document}
```

Here is the .log file as requested, hopefully this will solve weird issue.

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2013.2.27)  8 APR 2013 16:34
entering extended mode
**test.tex
(C:\Users\[redacted]\Desktop\test.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic, 
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2012-05-30, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian,
 lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, n
german-x-2012-05-30, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, roman
ian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swissgerm
an, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usengl
ishmax, welsh, loaded.
(D:\mikTeX\tex\latex\memoir\memoir.cls
Document Class: memoir 2011/03/06 v3.6j configurable book, report, article docu
ment class
\onelineskip=\skip41
\lxvchars=\skip42
\xlvchars=\skip43
\@memcnta=\count79
\c@@memmarkcntra=\count80
\l@nohyphenation=\language69
(D:\mikTeX\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
Package ifpdf Info: pdfTeX in PDF mode is detected.
)
(D:\mikTeX\tex\latex\ifetex\ifetex.sty
Package: ifetex 2011/12/15 v1.2 ifetex
 (D:\mikTeX\tex\plain\ifetex\ifetex.tex)) (D:\mikTeX\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxete
x.sty
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
(D:\mikTeX\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
\stockheight=\skip44
\stockwidth=\skip45
\trimtop=\skip46
\trimedge=\skip47

(D:\mikTeX\tex\latex\misc\etex.sty
Package: etex 1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
\et@xins=\count81
) (D:\mikTeX\tex\latex\memoir\mem10.clo
File: mem10.clo 2008/01/30 v0.3 memoir class 10pt size option
)
\binding=\skip48
\spinemargin=\skip49
\foremargin=\skip50
\uppermargin=\skip51
\lowermargin=\skip52
\headdrop=\skip53
\normalrulethickness=\skip54
\mem@maxheadheight=\skip55
\mem@maxfootheight=\skip56
\headwidth=\skip57
\c@storedpagenumber=\count82
\memPD=\dimen102
\m@mabparskip=\skip58
\thanksmarkwidth=\skip59
\thanksmarksep=\skip60
\droptitle=\skip61
\c@book=\count83
\c@part=\count84
\c@chapter=\count85
\c@section=\count86
\c@subsection=\count87
\c@subsubsection=\count88
\c@paragraph=\count89
\c@subparagraph=\count90
\beforechapskip=\skip62
\midchapskip=\skip63
\afterchapskip=\skip64
\chapindent=\skip65
\bottomsectionskip=\skip66
\secindent=\skip67
\beforesecskip=\skip68
\aftersecskip=\skip69
\subsecindent=\skip70
\beforesubsecskip=\skip71
\aftersubsecskip=\skip72
\subsubsecindent=\skip73
\beforesubsubsecskip=\skip74
\aftersubsubsecskip=\skip75
\paraindent=\skip76
\beforeparaskip=\skip77
\afterparaskip=\skip78
\subparaindent=\skip79
\beforesubparaskip=\skip80
\aftersubparaskip=\skip81
\pfbreakskip=\skip82
\c@@ppsavesec=\count91
\c@@ppsaveapp=\count92
\ragrparindent=\dimen103
\everylistparindent=\dimen104
\parsepi=\skip83
\topsepi=\skip84
\itemsepi=\skip85
\parsepii=\skip86
\topsepii=\skip87
\topsepiii=\skip88
\itemsepii=\skip89
\itemsepiii=\skip90
\partopsepii=\skip91
\partopsepiii=\skip92
\m@msavetopsep=\skip93
\m@msavepartopsep=\skip94
\@enLab=\toks14
\abstitleskip=\skip95
\absleftindent=\skip96
\abs@leftindent=\dimen105
\absrightindent=\skip97
\absparindent=\skip98
\absparsep=\skip99
\c@vslineno=\count93
\c@poemline=\count94
\c@modulo@vs=\count95
\c@memfvsline=\count96
\vleftskip=\skip100
\vrightskip=\skip101
\stanzaskip=\skip102
\versewidth=\skip103
\vgap=\skip104
\vindent=\skip105
\vleftmargin=\dimen106
\c@verse=\count97
\c@chrsinstr=\count98
\beforepoemtitleskip=\skip106
\afterpoemtitleskip=\skip107
\c@poem=\count99
\beforePoemTitleskip=\skip108
\midPoemTitleskip=\skip109
\afterPoemTitleskip=\skip110
\col@sep=\dimen107
\extrarowheight=\dimen108
\NC@list=\toks15
\extratabsurround=\skip111
\backup@length=\skip112
\TX@col@width=\dimen109
\TX@old@table=\dimen110
\TX@old@col=\dimen111
\TX@target=\dimen112
\TX@delta=\dimen113
\TX@cols=\count100
\TX@ftn=\toks16
\heavyrulewidth=\dimen114
\lightrulewidth=\dimen115
\cmidrulewidth=\dimen116
\belowrulesep=\dimen117
\belowbottomsep=\dimen118
\aboverulesep=\dimen119
\abovetopsep=\dimen120
\cmidrulesep=\dimen121
\cmidrulekern=\dimen122
\defaultaddspace=\dimen123
\@cmidla=\count101
\@cmidlb=\count102
\@aboverulesep=\dimen124
\@belowrulesep=\dimen125
\@thisruleclass=\count103
\@lastruleclass=\count104
\@thisrulewidth=\dimen126
\ctableftskip=\skip113
\ctabrightskip=\skip114
\abovecolumnspenalty=\count105
\@linestogo=\count106
\@cellstogo=\count107
\@cellsincolumn=\count108
\crtok=\toks17
\@mincolumnwidth=\dimen127
\c@newflo@tctr=\count109
\mem@margin@floatbox=\box26
\@contcwidth=\skip115
\@contindw=\skip116
\abovecaptionskip=\skip117
\belowcaptionskip=\skip118
\subfloattopskip=\skip119
\subfloatcapskip=\skip120
\subfloatcaptopadj=\skip121
\subfloatbottomskip=\skip122
\subfloatlabelskip=\skip123
\subfloatcapmargin=\dimen128
\c@@contsubnum=\count110
\m@mscap@capbox=\box27
\m@mscap@fbox=\box28
\sidecapsep=\dimen129
\sidecapwidth=\dimen130
\m@m@tempdima=\dimen131
\m@mscapraise=\dimen132
\sidecapraise=\dimen133
\m@mscapmainwidth=\dimen134
\m@mscaplkern=\dimen135
\beforeepigraphskip=\skip124
\afterepigraphskip=\skip125
\epigraphwidth=\skip126
\epigraphrule=\skip127
LaTeX Info: Redefining \em on input line 7377.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \emph on input line 7385.
\tocentryskip=\skip128
\tocbaseline=\skip129
\cftparskip=\skip130
\cftbeforebookskip=\skip131
\cftbookindent=\dimen136
\cftbooknumwidth=\dimen137
\cftbeforepartskip=\skip132
\cftpartindent=\skip133
\cftpartnumwidth=\skip134
\cftbeforechapterskip=\skip135
\cftchapterindent=\skip136
\cftchapternumwidth=\skip137
\cftbeforesectionskip=\skip138
\cftsectionindent=\skip139
\cftsectionnumwidth=\skip140
\cftbeforesubsectionskip=\skip141
\cftsubsectionindent=\skip142
\cftsubsectionnumwidth=\skip143
\cftbeforesubsubsectionskip=\skip144
\cftsubsubsectionindent=\skip145
\cftsubsubsectionnumwidth=\skip146
\cftbeforeparagraphskip=\skip147
\cftparagraphindent=\skip148
\cftparagraphnumwidth=\skip149
\cftbeforesubparagraphskip=\skip150
\cftsubparagraphindent=\skip151
\cftsubparagraphnumwidth=\skip152
\prechapterprecisshift=\dimen138
\c@maxsecnumdepth=\count111
\bibindent=\dimen139
\bibitemsep=\skip153
\indexcolsep=\skip154
\indexrule=\skip155
\indexmarkstyle=\toks18
\@indexbox=\insert233
\glossarycolsep=\dimen140
\glossaryrule=\dimen141
\sideparvshift=\skip156
\sideins=\insert232
\sidebartopsep=\skip157
\sidebarhsep=\skip158
\sidebarvsep=\skip159
\sidebarwidth=\skip160
\footmarkwidth=\skip161
\footmarksep=\skip162
\footparindent=\skip163
\footinsdim=\skip164
\footinsv@r=\insert231
\@mpfootinsv@r=\insert230
\m@m@k=\count112
\m@m@h=\dimen142
\m@mipn@skip=\skip165
\sidefootins=\insert229
\sidefootadjust=\skip166
\sidefootheight=\skip167
\sidefoothsep=\skip168
\sidefootvsep=\skip169
\sidefootwidth=\skip170
\m@mdownsf=\skip171
\c@sidefootnote=\count113
\sidefootmarkwidth=\skip172
\sidefootmarksep=\skip173
\sidefootparindent=\skip174
\c@pagenote=\count114
\c@pagenoteshadow=\count115
\mem@pn@lastkern=\skip175
\every@verbatim=\toks19
\afterevery@verbatim=\toks20
\verbatim@line=\toks21
\tab@position=\count116
\verbatim@in@stream=\read1
\verbatimindent=\skip176
\verbatim@out=\write3
\bvboxsep=\skip177
\c@memfbvline=\count117
\c@bvlinectr=\count118
\bvnumlength=\skip178
\fb@frw=\dimen143
\fb@frh=\dimen144
\FrameRule=\dimen145
\FrameSep=\dimen146
\c@cp@cntr=\count119
LaTeX Info: Redefining \: on input line 11807.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \! on input line 11809.
\c@ism@mctr=\count120
\c@xsm@mctr=\count121
\c@csm@mctr=\count122
\c@ksm@mctr=\count123
\c@xksm@mctr=\count124
\c@cksm@mctr=\count125
\c@msm@mctr=\count126
\c@xmsm@mctr=\count127
\c@cmsm@mctr=\count128
\c@bsm@mctr=\count129
\c@workm@mctr=\count130
\c@sheetsequence=\count131
\c@lastsheet=\count132
\c@lastpage=\count133
\c@figure=\count134
\c@lofdepth=\count135
\cftbeforefigureskip=\skip179
\cftfigureindent=\skip180
\cftfigurenumwidth=\skip181
\c@table=\count136
\c@lotdepth=\count137
\cftbeforetableskip=\skip182
\cfttableindent=\skip183
\cfttablenumwidth=\skip184
Package abstract [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package appendix [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package array [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package booktabs [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package ccaption [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package changepage [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package chngcntr [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package chngpage [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package crop emulated by memoir.
Package dcolumn [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package delarray [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package enumerate [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package epigraph [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package ifmtarg [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package index [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package makeidx [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package moreverb [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package mparhack [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package needspace [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package newfile [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package nextpage [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package pagenote [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package parskip [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package patchcmd [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package setspace [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package shortvrb [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package showidx [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package tabularx [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package titleref [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package titling [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package tocbibind [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package tocloft [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package tocvsec2 [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package verbatim [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package verse [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.

(D:\mikTeX\tex\latex\memoir\mempatch.sty
Package: mempatch 2009/07/24 v6.0f Patches for memoir class v1.6180339
)) (C:\Users\[redacted]\Desktop\test.aux)
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmss/m/it' in size <12> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/cmss/m/sl' tried instead on input line 4.

[1


{C:/Users/[redacted]/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
(C:\Users\[redacted]\Desktop\test.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 3545 strings out of 493921
 46328 string characters out of 3154503
 124281 words of memory out of 3000000
 6890 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 6747 words of font info for 24 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 841 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 24i,10n,20p,142b,208s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
<D:/mikTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr
10.pfb><D:/mikTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmssbx10.pfb><D:/mikTeX/fonts/
type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmssi12.pfb><D:/mikTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/
cmti12.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 33831 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 22 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: That only uses fonts which are available as type1 fonts so there should be no fixed resolution in the file at all. Look at the pdf you generate in acrobat or similar viewer that can list the fonts, they should all be type1 (and are when I process your file with pdflatex)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That is what I thought too. When I got the error, I was extremely surprised because I too thought they were just fonts but I don't know why `createspace` is not agreeing.

Comment: Fonts come in many different formats, show the pdflatex log (if you used pdflatex) and show what fonts a pdf viewer says are in the file.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The log file is very big, what portions should I show?

Comment: The log file from your MWE should not be that big (less than 400 lines) . If your MWE isn't showing the problem then it's not a good example:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have added the .log file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
D:/mikTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr
10.pfb><D:/mikTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmssbx10.pfb><D:/mikTeX/fonts/
type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmssi12.pfb><D:/mikTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/
cmti12.pfb>
```

So that file just uses pfb fonts (scalable type 1 postscript fonts in binary form) and doesn't include any bitmap images, and so the output does not depend on resolution in any essential way.

Either your real file is different: including type3 fonts or it includes bitmap images, or someone is wrong about it being resolution dependent.

Comment: Alright, If someone has to argue then I will show them this answer :) How should I be compiling my tex file for the best quality? Or does pdflatex do the best quality already?